'HtmlToDocx' object has no attribute 'run'
The parser is giving "HtmlToDocx object has no attribute run". When I do a search, I look at the stackoverflow results first because the answers are rated. I did not find an answer for this question on stackoverflow.

There is a bug. It is reported on https://github.com/pqzx/html2docx/issues/37.
The issue is if there is a <br> at the beginning of the document or at the beginning of a table data <td> the parser throws this error.
I made sure my html did not have these cases, but it still didn't work. I found that <br> in other locations can also throw this error. To test this, I removed all <br> and the parser had no problem.
If I get the time, I'll try to zero in on more specific uses of <br> that are causing the error and I'll add them here.
